# Ignite cache - atomic operation to update cache entry only if condition is met

Tags: ignite

I'd like to know if there is a way to do atomic update to the cache entry conditionally, ie. for example something like this:

```
cache.putCondtitionally(key, newEntity, (oldEntity, newEntity) -> oldEntity.timestamp().isBefore(newEntity.timestamp()))
```

My concrete use-case is, that I receive updates to the entities which can be out of order, and I do not want to overwrite the entity already in the cache with "older" one. I'm OK if I miss some updates.

I'd like to manage this on cache in ATOMIC mode (no locks, no transactions).

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a copy of the old object, you can use `IgniteCache#replace(key, oldValue, newValue)`.

For something more complex you can use an [entry processor](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jcache#entryprocessor), which uses the `IgniteCache#invoke()` method.

Comment: I already experimented with replace(), but invoke() looks like a thing I'm looking for. I'll give it a try. Thx!